# Is it possible to embed gradle plugin in jar?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, executable-jar

There are multiple Java applications (jars which are built and maintained independently) that we run during build using custom task types for each application.

These custom tasks are usually project.exec on jar files with @Input properties and some preprocessing.

One idea is to have all custom tasks for all such jars in one separate plugin.

Another is to have one gradle plugin for each of those Java applications.

I think it would be much simpler if we can make gradle plugin or custom tasks and embed them with those jars so that they can just be imported in another project and those tasks can be used?

Is there a way to do that? Is it a standard problem with a standard solution?

Comment: you mean have a plugin that will define some tasks (these are really extensions) that can be applied to some projects? If so, isn't this what plugins do - to begin with? I feel like I am losing your point, so you might want to explain better

Comment: @Eugene Can I have a gradle plugin (extension) embeded inside those java apps. This should allow importing them as libs and using their gradle tasks. This should probably also enable running those tasks from command line (gradle way). Gradle plugins as standalone project (JAR) https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html let us import and use that plugin. That JAR is a gradle plugin. Can I have my original java app alongside within that same JAR?

Comment: A Gradle plugin is a jar (at least if you create is as [standalone project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project)). This jar can contain as many classes as you want or need and can even have dependencies on other jars. The plugin creates the tasks you want and you can call these tasks the same way as any other plugin-generated task (like for example `compileJava`)

Comment: @ThomasKläger So it means that plugin jar can have the manifest file with main class and can be executed as a java application `java -jar <plugin>.jar`?

Comment: Yes, this is entirely possible. You can take the `build.gradle` file from the example and configure the `jar` task to include a `Main-Class` attribute in the manifest.